# Format in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of values as follows:

```
no column
1. 111-222-11
2. 112-333-12
3. 113-444-13
```

I want to format the value from `111-222-11` to `111-222-011` and format the other values similarly. Here is my code snippet in Python 3, which I am trying to use for that:

```
‘{:03}-{:06}-{:03}.format(column)
```

I hope that you can help.

Comment: Better ask on *StackOverflow*.

Comment: I can not figure out what you are asking: Where are the columns? What have you tried (show code, not just a bit, but not more than needed)?

Comment: Is the list stored in a text file? Do you need it to be written back to the text file? Is your script necessary to be in Python or can it be `bash`, for example?

Comment: Do you just need to add the leading zero before the last of the three values separated by "-"? Are all of the input values expected to be of the same lengths (3 digits, 3 digits, 2 digits)?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `column` is a variable that can be assigned string values `111-222-11`, `112-333-12`, `113-444-13` and so on, which you want to change to `111-222-011`, `112-333-012`, `113-444-013` and so on, it appears that you tried to use a combination of slice notation and `format` method to achieve this.

### Slice notation

Slice notation, when applied to a string, treats it as a list-like object consisting of characters. The positional index of a character from the beginning of the string starts from zero. The positional index of a character from the end of the string starts with `-1`. The first colon `:` separates the beginning and the end of a slice. The end of the slice is not included into it, unlike its beginning. You indicate slices as you would indicate indexes of items in a list by using square brackets:

```py
'111-222-11'[0:8]
```

would return

```py
'111-222-'
```

Usually, the indexes of the first and the last characters of the string are skipped and implied by the colon.

Knowing the exact position where you need to add a leading zero before the last two digits of a string assigned to `column`, you could do it just with slice notation:

```py
column[:8] + '0' + column[-2:]
```

### `format` method

The `format` method is a string formatting method. So, you want to use single quotes or double quotes around your strings to indicate them when applying that method to them:

```py
'your output string here'.format('your input string here')
```

The numbers in the curly brackets are not slices. They are placeholders, where the strings, which are passed to the `format` method, are inserted. So, combining slices and `format` method, you could add a leading zero before the last two digits of a `column` string like this:

```py
'{0}0{1}'.format(column[:8], column[-2:])
```

Making more slices is not necessary because there is only one place where you want to insert a character.

### `split` method

An alternative to slicing would be using `split` method to split the string by a delimiter. The `split` method returns a list of strings. You need to prefix it with `*` operator to unpack the arguments from the list before passing them to the `format` method. Otherwise, the whole list will be passed to the first placeholder.

```py
'{0}-{1}-0{2}'.format(*column.split('-'))
```

It splits the string into a list treating `-` as the separator and puts each item into a new string, which adds `0` character before the last one.